# Lock the group footer to the page bottom SSRS. Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, footer, reportbuilder3.0

How to lock the group footer to the page bottom in Report Builder 3.0?

I do not want to add Page Footer.

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't want add page footer?

Comment: The structure of my report is that first page doesn't contain footer, second page contains footer, third page doesn't contain footer, fourth page contains footer and so on... so when I add page footer ale pages contains footer.

Comment: You cannot control footer on specific pages. Hide the individual  elements inside footer using the visibility property.

Comment: But then I have trouble with footer border. I added border to footer and report body and there is a gap between footer and report's body.

Comment: Change the footer border dynamically using expression or add a line instead of footer border.

Comment: OneZeroPundit, could you explain this?